# Removing print statement causes program to crash C

Tags: c

I have a c program where I copy one string to another but for some reason in my loop, if I remove a print statement I used for debugging once, the program crashes before I reach the print statement outside the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char * cats2 = malloc(sizeof(char));
    cats2[0] = '\0';
    char * cats = "this string is a cool cat";
    getCopyFrom(cats, cats2);
    free(cats2);
    return 0;
}

void getCopyFrom(char* original, char* translation){
    int index = 0;
    char * current = malloc(sizeof(char));
    current[0] = '\0';
    while(index < (strlen(original))){
        printf("%d\n", index);
        current = realloc(current, sizeof(char) * 2);
        current[index] = original[index];
        current[index + 1] = '\0';
        index++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", current);
    free(current);
}
```

If I remove the `printf("%d\n", index);` from the while loop, the program will crash before the while loop ends.  If I keep it, the program runs fine until the end where it returns a access violation error.

I'm not sure why either happens, am I missing something obvious or am I just not understanding malloc and realloc correctly?

edit:)

My previous question was answered, but I have a new problem. I added translation = realloc(translation, (strlen(current) + 1) * sizeof(char)); to the code to set the size of translation to the size of current but I get another access violation. Are you not able to realloc parameters or something?

Comment: You are only ever reallocating with two bytes for the string.  So unless you are building a string that only contains one character plus a null-terminator, then you're going to run off the end.  Perhaps you meant to realloc a size of `(index+2) * sizeof(char)`

Comment: realloc does not add whatever you say to the existing size; it changes the size to that value ... so doing `realloc(pointer, some_constant);` does not change the size at all (except the very first time it is executed).

Comment: By the way, there's no point in allocating this way.  You already know the required size of the final string: it is `strlen(original) + 1`.  So why not just `malloc` that and then copy the string over (with `strncpy` or `memcpy`).

Comment: Oh jeez, for some reason I thought realloc added on to the existing memory.  Okay, thank you for the help, I was able to fix it and now it's working.

Comment: @paddy I was doing it this way because this was the start of a larger project so this was basically me starting the basics of it.

Comment: Okay so I understand that realloc doesn't add to the memory, but I have a new problem.  I added `translation = realloc(translation, (strlen(current) + 1) * sizeof(char));` to the code to set the size of translation to the size of current but I get another access violation.  Are you not able to realloc parameters or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
current = realloc(current, sizeof(char) * 2);
```

but why is the second argument to `realloc()` in a loop a constant? It's like we want

```
current = realloc(current, sizeof(char) * (index + 1));
```

but once you do that you'll discover your code is really slow. The `* 2` meant something. You really want to keep a separate array size and allocated size, and only call realloc when array size == allocated size and double allocated size.

```
if (index + 1 >= alloc) {
    char *new = realloc(current, sizeof(char) * (alloc = (alloc == 0) ? 4 : (alloc << 1)));
    if (!new) {
        /* todo handle error */
    }
}
```

Comment: No,  incrementing allocated space by `1` is not slow. It is only marginally slower than larger increments, or doubling the size. I have tested (GNU/linux) multiple resize strategies when adding loop iterator as single byte to an array. The maximum slowdown I saw was 2x for single increment compared to the best speed. Probably `realloc` already knows the best strategy, and the slowdown I saw was a simple function call overhead.

Comment: @HAL9000: I saw a quadratic explosion a few years ago. Maybe your maximum size is too low to measure. The allocation chunk size is at least 32 bytes so sizes changes smaller than that are noops.

Comment: What system did you test on? My total size was 1GB. I also tried to introduce fragmentation, but didn't see any difference. Probably the results would be different on a 32-bit system.